# What are currently the best reported qubit error rates per gate operation?

Tags: experimental-realization, superconducting-quantum-computing, decoherence, photonics, trapped-ion

Based on some investigation, I have found the best qubit coherence timescales, in superconducting architectures, to be the order of milliseconds.
https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.94.014506
Considering the gate operation timescales, typical qubit error rates per gate operation are in order of 0.001 to 0.01.

And the trapped ion qubit here supposedly has one hour coherence time
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-20330-w
However, gate timescales are not clear.

Are qubit error rates per gate operation in order of 0.001 to 0.01 the state of the art? Please share coherence timescales and gate timescales for other modern qubits if you know.

Comment: Can I suggest a slightly different metric that makes different systems more comparable? A ratio of T1/T2 time to single-qubit gate time. It's no use have hours of coherence time if it takes you days to do one operation!

Comment: I agree. 
Can I modify the question accordingly?

Comment: Yes, you can edit your own question. Just click the edit link in the bottom left.